# How to evaluate if a row was selected from a Flow: Data Table component

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-datatable, screen-flow

I have a Flow with a Data Table component, and afterwards I have a decision node where I want to evaluate if any row was selected from the previous Data Table. I have tried the following approaches without success, any idea?

1)
[image]

2)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to assign the count of the selected rows output from the data table component to a variable in your flow and use a 'greater than' operator in your decision.

To do this, immediately after the screen that contains the data table add an Assignment node that assigns the 'Equals Count' of the SelectedRows attribute of your data table to a variable of type Number.

[image]

Then in your decision node, simply use this number variable to determine what branch you need to follow.

[image]

Comment: Great approach @callum MacErlich! Thanks it worked!